# Obfuscate WebExtension allowed?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I've developed my first addon using the WebExtension api.

Is it allowed to obfuscate my background and options javascript files? (for example removing all newlines and/or rename my descriptive variable names)

There is a little note in the "Signing and distributing your add-on" doc:

> You should not obfuscate your code to bypass validation warnings.  That practice can lead to your add-on being rejected and
>   potentially blacklisted.
>
> ```
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Distribution
> ```

But if i understand correctly this only regarding obfuscation to bypass warnings.

Comment: Minification is not obfuscation.

Comment: Indeed @wOxxOm , interesting read on the subject: http://www.differencebetween.info/difference-between-minification-and-obfuscation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is permitted to obfuscate or minimize your code. Mozilla's [Review Policies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/AMO/Policy/Reviews) are quite clear regarding [Review Policies:Source Code Submission](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/AMO/Policy/Reviews#Source_Code_Submission):

> Listed and unlisted add-ons may contain binary, obfuscated and minified source code, but Mozilla must be allowed to review a copy of the human-readable source code upon request. In such cases, the author will receive a message  from Mozilla asking for their assistance in the review. The submitted source code will be reviewed by an administrator and will not be redistributed in any way. The code will only be used for the purpose of reviewing the add-on.
>
> Instructions for reproducing obfuscation are also required, please read [the details of this guideline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/Source_Code_Submission) to ensure a swift review.
>
> If your add-on contains code that you don't own or can't get the source code for, you may [contact us](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/AMO/Policy/Contact) for information on how to proceed.

There is, in fact, a page dedicated to describing [Source Code Submission](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Source_Code_Submission) (linked in the quote above).

The basics of the requirements are that if you choose to minimize or obfuscate your code, then you need to:

1. Upload the unminimized and unobfuscated code as part of the submission to AMO (this version of the code is not distributed; it's only used for review).
2. Provide detailed instructions of how to produce the minimized/obfuscated code. They must be able to exactly reproduce the minimized/obfuscated code you have provided.

Providing minimized/obfuscated code will increase the amount of time required for your review. Your review will be an "admin" review which has a much smaller pool of reviewers, which is part of what makes it take longer.

Comment: Cheers @Makyen for the extensive reply and explanation. I appreciate it!